# Can't reach the settings in my android app

Tags: android

I'm developing movie android app that takes its data via API and there are two ways to display movies by popularity or top rates i use settings to choose among these two ways but when i press settings the app crashes.

This is the MainActivity

```
package com.example.ahmed.moviesapp;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String Target_URL = "";
ArrayList <Movie> MoviesList ;
GridView movieGrid ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    showUserSettings();

    movieGrid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        MoviesList = (ArrayList<Movie>)    
savedInstanceState.getSerializable("movies");
        afterAsync();

    }
   else {
        Task mytask = new Task(this);
        mytask.execute("1","2","3");
    }



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main
            , menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, UserSettingActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            break;

    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent   
data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            showUserSettings();
            break;

    }

}

private void showUserSettings() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    Target_URL =  
sharedPrefs.getString("sortby","http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?  
api_key=###################");

}





private void afterAsync (){

    MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(MainActivity.this ,   
R.layout.single_item, MoviesList);
    adapter.printfun();
    movieGrid.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putSerializable("movies", MoviesList);
}

private class Task extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    public  ProgressDialog dialog;
    Context context;
    ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection();
    public Task(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
        afterAsync ();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        String jsonToParse = connection.getDatat(Target_URL);
        Log.e("Error",Target_URL);
        MoviesList = JsonParser.MoviesParser(jsonToParse);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

UserSettingActivity

```
public class UserSettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
}
}
```

menu_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    ic_menu_preferences=""
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Settings"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"/>

</menu>
```

array.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string-array name="sortby">
    <item>View By Top Rated</item>
    <item>View By Highest Popularity</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="sortbyvalues">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">MoviesApp</string>
<string name="title">View By</string>
<string name="sortbysummary">Set the method you prefer</string>


<string name="popular">http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?        
 api_key=######</string>
<string name="top_rated">http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated? 
api_key=#######</string>
</resources>
```

settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="Settings" >

    <ListPreference
        android:key="sortbyKey"
        android:entries="@array/sortby"
        android:summary="@string/sortbysummary"
        android:entryValues="@array/sortbyvalues"
        android:title="@string/title" />

</PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Logcat

```
08-26 23:36:49.369 31552-31552/com.example.ahmed.moviesapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.example.ahmed.moviesapp.Movie@4064c140
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1132)
at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:519)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1092)
at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityPaused(ActivityManagerNative.java:1622)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what error are you receiving?

Comment: @Juvie22 I added the logcat

Comment: Try [googling the error message](https://www.google.com/#q=java.lang.RuntimeException%3A+Parcel%3A+unable+to+marshal+value).

Comment: Does the movie class implement `Parcelable`?

Comment: thanks the movie class should implement **Serializable**

Comment: Parcelable is more preferred for performance reasons, but there's more code to write